# Weird ActionBarSherlock behavior when starting an Action Mode on Gingerbread

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock in my android app, the theme is set to `Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`, when I run the app on ICS devices , everything looks ok, 
but when I test it on Gingerbread (both emu and on multiple devices) the action bar looks weird, sometimes when it loses focus it becomes white.

I'm not using custom styles, so I can't quite understand what may be causing this.

**Update:**
I have noticed that this is actually happening each time I'm entering and exiting an Action Mode programmatically (`StartActionMode`).

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem, it occurred because I started and stopped the action mode very fast.